# Can I capture "Unrecognized escape" warning when compiling a regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm reading a regular expression from a configuration file, which may or may not have invalid syntax in it. (It's locked down behind a firewall, so let's not get into security.)  I've been able to test for a number of errors and give a friendly message.

No such luck on this one:

> `Unrecognized escape \Q passed through in regex`

I know what causes it, I just want to know if I can capture it in Perl 5.8. So far it has resisted my efforts to check for this condition.

So the question is: does anybody know how to capture this? Do I have to redirect STDERR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the warning FATAL and use block eval:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = '\M';

my $r = eval {
    use warnings FATAL => qw( regexp );
    qr/$s/;
};

$r or die "Runtime regexp compilation produced:\n$@\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to turn this warning to an error:

```
sub un {
  local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    die $_[0] if $_[0]=~/^Unrecognized escape /;
    print STDERR $_[0]
  };
  qr{$_[0]}
}
un('al\Fa');
print "Not reached.\n";
```

Here is how to ignore this warning:

```
sub un {
  local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    print STDERR $_[0] if $_[0]!~/^Unrecognized escape /;
  };
  qr{$_[0]}
}
un('al\Fa');
print "Reached.\n";
```

Comment: to ignore a warning it is better to use   "no warnings 'warning_category';"

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a warning, you'd need to redirect `STDERR` as well.

My guess is you're getting the warning because you're interpolating the regex string you get from the configuration file - try `s/\\/\\\\/g` on the regex string before using it.

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant: STDERR -- actually on first typing it was STOUT. :D